# Time complexity of Separating Axis Theorem

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, complexity-theory, separating-axis-theorem

How would you determine the complexity based on the number of polygons (triangles)? Please correct or confirm my approach here.
Assuming we have a pyramid and start adding a vertices. From six vertices I see a pattern like this:

```
number of polygons = number of vertices * 2 - 2
```

In SAT I project each vertex of an object to each of its normal. So the formula is N*V where N is the same as number of polygons so :

```
(V*2-2)*V = 2V^2 - 2V
```

Is this correct? If so, what kind of complexity is this? Should I call it a combination of quadratic and linear? Thanks.

EDIT: Now looking at it I guess it depends on how I triangulate, it might be also:

```
number of polygons = number of vertices * 2 - 4
```

Not sure if it's minimal but it shouldn't change the complexity. It's just a constant. So V*2-A maybe.
Please let me know if there's some kind of formula. I found just the Euler's polyhedron formula that deals with edges as well.

Comment: O(ax^2+bx+c) = O(x^2)

Comment: @MooseBoys Thank you, so quadratic. I didn't realize that I can apply the quadratic equation instead of simple x^2.

Comment: It's not the quadratic equation, rather for big-Oh complexity analysis you simply take the "largest" term, e.g. O(x^2+e^x) = O(e^x).

Comment: @MooseBoys I get it, many thanks for the explanation.